# How to export a global checkstyle ruleset in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

I have been searching around for about an hour now and can't find out how to export a 'global' checkstyle ruleset XML from eclipse. I made one a few years ago and put it into my eclipse as a global ruleset alongside the default Google Checks and Sun Checks, but for the life of me can't find where in the file system those are stored. Does anyone know? I know I had to manually edit it in the filesystem to get changes and take a copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are located in workspace.metadata.plugins\net.sf.eclipsecs.core and each file is named internal_config_########.xml where #### is a timestamp or something.